# Android login in my app with google credentials

Tags: android, google-account

HI I'm developing an application in wich I want to permit the user to login to my server with his Google account without asking him the credentials because I know that are saved into the AccountManager class.
The problem is that I don't know how to autenticate the user because the account ID is just stored in Google's server, so Where can I find an ID for the account and how can I use it to autenticate user? I'd like to follow these steps: user choose one of the stored account, I get an id, send it from the terminal to the server, and I answere that "he trust" this user, after this I save this id in my server and request an auth token to Google just to use it between my server and the application on android device.

Comment: https://androidbeasts.wordpress.com/2015/08/22/android-login-using-google/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
List<String> googleAccounts = new ArrayList<String>();
Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(this).getAccounts();
for (Account account : accounts) {
  if (account.type.equals("com.google")) {
    googleAccounts.add(account.name);
  }
}
```

You can see a more detailed example in the code of the ChromeToPhone app open-sourced by Google: http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#JWblrwroAxw/trunk/android/src/com/google/android/apps/chrometophone/MainActivity.java&l=311

Comment: Plus this, perhaps?: https://github.com/kaeppler/signpost-examples/blob/master/OAuthGoogleExample/src/GoogleMain.java

Comment: Ok, but, if I got the google account, than, to autenticate the user without asking him to insert the credentials, is sufficient the authToken?

Comment: The user won't have to insert the credentials. He will have to allow your app to access this account.

Comment: How can I create the request to allow my application to access the account?

Comment: Android will handle the request when you try to access the account.

Comment: @DavidLeonard: The link is broken now, fixed one: https://github.com/mttkay/signpost-examples/blob/master/OAuthGoogleExample/src/GoogleMain.java