# Google Login For Android App

Tags: android, gmail

How Can I integrate Gmail(Google) to login to my APP. I searched this site but no success. Any link or any Source code or any tutorial to login Using Gmail in My Application.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking here

https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/MobileApps

This should give an idea of how it is to be done.

Duplicate question : [Android login in my app with google credentials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4553004/android-login-in-my-app-with-google-credentials)

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at this:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/